# How to save text data and save image in a server folder using angular, nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, file-upload

How to save text data to mongodb database and store image to server folder. 
I am using nodejs as server side language and angular as client and mongodb as database.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { ADDGOD_URL } from '../utils/urls';
import { httpOptions } from '../utils/httpheader';
import { GodModel } from '../../model/godmodel';

@Injectable()
export class GodService {
imageFile: File;
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

addGod(godObject: GodModel): Observable<any> {
let fileList: FileList = godObject.imageEvent.target.files;
if (fileList.length > 0) {
    this.imageFile = fileList[0];
}

let data = 
{
"name": godObject.name,
"othername": godObject.othername,
"epithet": godObject.epithet,
"gender": godObject.gender,
"weapon": godObject.weapon,
"instrument": godObject.instrument,
"vehicle": godObject.vehicle,
"mantra": godObject.mantra,
"stotra": godObject.stotra,
"yantra": godObject.yantra,
"incarnation": godObject.incarnation,
"family": godObject.family,
"apprearance": godObject.apprearance,
"place": godObject.place,
"subincarnation": godObject.subincarnation,
"aarti": godObject.aarti,
"story": godObject.story,
"knownfor": godObject.knownfor,
"poojaitem": godObject.poojaitem,
"books": godObject.books,
"dosdonts": godObject.dosdonts,
"festival": godObject.festival,
"ritual": godObject.ritual,
"abode": godObject.abode,
"type": godObject.type,
"form": godObject.form,
"auspicioustime": godObject.auspicioustime,
"image": this.imageFile
};
return this.httpClient.post<any>(ADDGOD_URL, data, httpOptions);
}
}
```

I have made a sample code to save plain data separately and a different code to save image in a folder and its path to mongodb.
But now I have to do both the task in a single project.

Comment: Use [npm busboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy)

Comment: with image upload, my angular service looks like:
let data = 
      {
        "stotra": godObject.stotra,
        "yantra": godObject.yantra,
        "incarnation": godObject.incarnation,
        "family": godObject.family,
        "apprearance": godObject.apprearance,
        "place": godObject.place,
        "subincarnation": godObject.subincarnation,
        "aarti": godObject.aarti,
      };
    return this.httpClient.post<any>(ADDGOD_URL, data, httpOptions);
now here what I have to change when I have to save data as well as image?
Thanks for the help @Ashish.

Comment: @Ashish, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I have used Multer to upload images on sever folder and stores its name into database.

here is my code,

```
storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, uploadFn) {
        uploadFn(null, path.join(__dirname, '../public/uploads/'));
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        if (file) {
            var isimage = isImage(file.originalname);
            if (isimage) {
                cb(null, file.originalname)
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
});

var upload = multer({
    storage: storage
});
```

#### I have to upload multiple images, therefore use upload.arrayconst

```
route.post('/addgod', upload.array('images', 5), (req, res) => {
    // get all fields
    var name = req.body.name;
    var othername = req.body.othername;
    var epithet = req.body.epithet

    // construct a model
    let godObj = new godModel(name, othername, epithet);

    const godcrud = require('../db/god/godcrud');
    godcrud.addGodDetails(godObj, res); // call a function to save data on database
});
```